# bad Review audit with "correct" answers

Tags: discussion, review-audits

There are a few audits with answers which are not good but in my opinion a valid answer.

Like this one

> put the src for jquery ui below jquery. As the jqueryui uses jquery.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/7908390

This could be a perfect valid answer, but apparently its not.

Should I do something better or is this a bad audit?

Comment: You can leave a comment and suggest more detail, otherwise it should be a comment.

Comment: You need ~50rep or so to leave comments, I agree that this is not a good answer but I don't see why this couldn't be a valid answer

Comment: The irritating thing is that this is (per the comment, which is not shown before the audit) blatantly wrong, as even a quick look at the question can show with little or no specific technical knowledge. That's not a very useful answer. In context, with the comment, I would be strongly tempted to go ahead and hit Recommend Deletion in Low-Quality Posts. Sure, it's an answer; sure, technical accuracy isn't the point of review, but this answer *can't work* on this question. The problem comes in the nature of the audit, really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This could be a perfect valid answer, but apparently its not.

Sure it is. I mean, it's a perfectly valid, unhelpful, *wrong* answer, but a perfectly valid one none the less. And poorly-written. But still valid.

...Maybe "perfect" is the wrong word here. The answer was valid, but *it had problems.*

Anyway, here are the review instructions you were given:

[image]

You chose No Action Needed. So either you didn't notice that the answer was badly in need of some downvoting, commenting and perhaps editing or even flagging... Or you just didn't feel like doing any of those things.

Either way, that's not what the situation required. Please learn from this.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad audit. The answer is apparently wrong (according to people who know JavaScript), but it *is* an attempt at offering a solution to the problem in the question (as opposed to, say, a stylistic comment). None of the justifications that users with less than 20K rep are allowed to use to recommend answer deletion apply here, so it should not be an audit.

Possibly it could be used as an audit for 20K+ rep users (who *are* allowed to vote to delete negatively-scored answers on the grounds of being technically incorrect), but not for <20K rep users.